Conflicting peer dependency vite@6.06 while installing @vercel/analytics to a Nuxt 3 App
The app runs good both locally and in production.
Three months ago I did another project using Nuxt 3 which has @vercel/analytics installed in him. Installing it using npm i @vercel/analytics worked. Now, 3 months later, for some reason I can't install it. I don't understand what could've changed in such short period.
There are potential solutions, but they are bad for a project's longevity and they are more workarounds than solutions. To fix the conflict I can try to:

Use the flag --legacy-peer-deps which ignores peer dependecy conflicts but this could lead to issues.

But I don't want to expose my self to further, more complex issues. What should I do? I really cannot find any satisfying answer on the web or with ChatGPT.

Depends on the conflicts. Quite a few things could move, starting by the version of NodeJS. You could also switch from NPM to PNPM, this could fix quite a few issues while still being low-hanging fruit. Otherwise, your package.json also probably uses caret ranges for its dependencies, hence some packages might not be fully frozen. I am not sure about the workarounds proposed because you are quite lightweight on details as a whole. But keep in mind that if you use any kind of platfrom + meta-framework, you'll need to have a constant maintenance. It's not a Go server on a bare metal VPS.
